# Android handle deep link with a slash in the end of the URL

Tags: android, deep-linking

I want to handle some deep links with a slash in the end of the URL in Android, such as:

```
https://www.xxx.xxx/mobile/

https://www.xxx.xxx/mobile
```

The one has a slash in the end of the URL and the other one doesn't have.

I want to use

```
<data
 android:host="www.xxx.xxx"
 android:pathPattern="/mobile/?"
 android:scheme="https" />
```

to handle it, but it doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple pathPattern:

```
<data android:host="www.xxx.xxx" android:pathPattern="/mobile" android:scheme="https" />
<data android:host="www.xxx.xxx" android:pathPattern="/mobile/" android:scheme="https" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
android:pathPattern="/mobile/?"
```

use

```
android:pathPattern="/mobile.?"
```